# View state lost between onActivityResult and onResume

Tags: android, fragment, lifecycle, onactivityresult

I’m using `startActivityForResult()` to capture an image from the camera. While testing with the developer option “Don’t keep activities”, I noticed that my view state is being correctly restored in `onViewStateRestored`, but then is lost again before `onActivityResult` gets called. Looks like a second instance of the same fragment is being created; there are two calls to `onCreate`, one with a valid `savedInstanceState`, and another with `savedInstanceState == null`. The first one never gets to `onResume`.

This is what I see in the logs:

```
E/CaptureFragment﹕ fireTakePictureIntent: tempPhotoPath: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_2014-10-15 23.19.45.jpg
E/CaptureFragment﹕ startActivityForResult: tempPhotoPath: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_2014-10-15 23.19.45.jpg
I/am_on_paused_called﹕ [0,com.chimbori.galapagos.views.capture.CaptureActivity]
E/CaptureFragment﹕ onSaveInstanceState: tempPhotoPath: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_2014-10-15 23.19.45.jpg
E/CaptureFragment﹕ onCreate: tempPhotoPath: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_2014-10-15 23.19.45.jpg
E/CaptureFragment﹕ onViewStateRestored: tempPhotoPath: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_2014-10-15 23.19.45.jpg
E/CaptureFragment﹕ onCreate: tempPhotoPath: null
E/CaptureFragment﹕ onStart
E/CaptureFragment﹕ onActivityResult : tempPhotoPath: null
E/CaptureFragment﹕ onResume: tempPhotoPath: null
I/am_on_resume_called﹕ [0,com.chimbori.galapagos.views.capture.CaptureActivity]
```

The methods are straightforward:

```
private String tempPhotoPath;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(IntentConstants.EXTRA_PHOTO_FILE)) {
    tempPhotoPath = savedInstanceState.getString(IntentConstants.EXTRA_PHOTO_FILE);
  }
  Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: tempPhotoPath: " + tempPhotoPath);
}

private void fireTakePictureIntent() {
  Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
    tempPhotoPath = FilePaths.createTempPhotoPath().getAbsolutePath();
    Log.e(TAG, "fireTakePictureIntent: tempPhotoPath: " + tempPhotoPath);
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(tempPhotoPath)));
    Log.e(TAG, "startActivityForResult: tempPhotoPath: " + tempPhotoPath);
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  if (tempPhotoPath != null) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState: tempPhotoPath: " + tempPhotoPath);
    outState.putString(IntentConstants.EXTRA_PHOTO_FILE, tempPhotoPath);
  }
}

@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
  if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(IntentConstants.EXTRA_PHOTO_FILE)) {
    tempPhotoPath = savedInstanceState.getString(IntentConstants.EXTRA_PHOTO_FILE);
    Log.e(TAG, "onViewStateRestored: tempPhotoPath: " + tempPhotoPath);
  }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult : tempPhotoPath: " + tempPhotoPath);
  }
}
```

Any ideas why it would get restored correctly on `onViewStateRestored` but go back to null in `onActivityResult` and beyond?

Comment: put android:config inside activity manifest

Comment: @Dipu I think you meant android:configChanges, because there's no such thing as android:config in the manifest. And that is not a solution because this is not an activity config change, it's starting a whole new activity and then returning to an old one.

Comment: yeah I meant that Starting whole new activity means ?? is onActivityResult being called or not?

Comment: I see twice onCreate(). The second time may be the another instance.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured it out. I was re-creating the `CaptureFragment` in the `CaptureActivity` even when I was being passed a non-null `savedInstanceState`. That explains why two fragments were being created instead of one.

Before fix: `CaptureActivity.onCreate`

```
CaptureFragment captureFragment = new CaptureFragment();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.activity_capture_content_frame, captureFragment,
        CaptureFragment.class.getCanonicalName())
    .commit();
```

Fixed:

```
CaptureFragment captureFragment = (savedInstanceState != null)
    ? (CaptureFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CaptureFragment.class.getCanonicalName())
    : new CaptureFragment();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.activity_capture_content_frame, captureFragment,
        CaptureFragment.class.getCanonicalName())
    .commit();
```